Is using-declaration with an anonymous enum valid in modern C++
I know that the following typedef-based code works fine and is widely used:
class Example {
public:
    typedef enum {
        eOrdered,
        eRandom
    } tePoolOrder;
};

Clang-tidy has now automatically modernized it as follows.
class Example {
public:
    using tePoolOrder = enum {
        eOrdered,
        eRandom
    };
};

This compiles without issues in my C++17-setup (Clang/GCC), but I’m unsure whether this syntax is standard-compliant or if it relies on compiler-specific behavior.
I understand that using typically aliases named types, so is this usage with an anonymous enum supported by the C++ standard? If not, should I switch to a named enum for portability? What would be the correct modern C++ approach to achieve this?
Any clarification would be appreciated!
Try it out here: https://onlinegdb.com/3FuchkJ5Y

enum class tePoolOrder { ... }; that's what other devs expect and that's what you should write

Just like class and structure names are valid type-names, so are enumeration names. No need for creating a type-alias, just give the enumeration its name.

I'm primarily interested in whether this is standard-compliant. I'm asking because Clang-Tidy automatically modernized it like this in many places for me, and I'm not entirely sure I trust it.

Yes, it is valid.   But, like the typedef (which is a hang-over from pretty ancient C) the using form in this case is unnecessary.   You can eliminate both - and achieve the same effect - by simply doing enum tePoolOrder {eOrdered, eRandom};  or  (since C++11, if you seek the additional safety)   enum class tePoolOrder {eOrdered, eRandom};

Also, if you want to "modernize" the code, you could also get rid of the te and e prefixes, which are also warts from old "hungarian" C code. Especially if te no longer means typedef enum. Using PoolOrder::Random would be perfectly clear.

If you think aliasing enums, or other class types, is widely used you have been looking at a very narrow selection of C++.

Simplified, the syntax of using for type-aliases is
using alias = type;

For your case the alias is tePoolOrder and the type is enum { ... }.
This is perfectly valid.

This is very similar to typedef, which has the syntax (again simplified):
typedef type alias;

Hopefully this helps to see that the type is the same, and that enum { ... } is a type and not an anonymous enumeration.

Ok, then it is a general property of the using alias that it can be applied to ANY type, regardless of whether that type has a name or not?

@SoulfreezerXP Yes, it can be used for any type. For your Example class it could be used as using Example2 = Example; as well. Or using my_special_int = int;. Or even using my_class = class { ... };

Or indeed using exprType = decltype(some horrible expression)

A non-template alias declaration has exactly the same semantics as the equivalent typedef declaration: using X = Y; is exactly the same as typedef Y X;. That's how the using alias declaration is defined. The two can be arbitrarily interchanged.
So, given that the first example is valid, the second is also.

Your answer was also correct and helpful. I chose another one as it had a bit more detail relevant to my case. I appreciate your input!

There's no need for either a typedef or a using statements in C++ (the typedef style comes from C).
You can simply use:
class Example {
public:
    enum class tePoolOrder {
        eOrdered,
        eRandom
    };
};

Note that I used a scoped enum which is recommended in C++. In order to use the scoped enum values you need tePoolOrder::eOrdered (or Example::tePoolOrder::eOrdered if you are outside the class) etc.
You can also do the same with an unscoped enum (although I don't see the benefit in that):
class Example {
public:
    enum tePoolOrder {
        eOrdered,
        eRandom
    };
};


Yes, the alternatives make sense, but my primary concern is being able to assess whether Clang-Tidy hasn't broken anything.

@SoulfreezerXP not sure I understand. You can simply get rid of the typedef/using. It's perfectly valid standard C++. Clang-tidy should not raise any issue with that.

@SoulfreezerXP can you please clarify why do you need the typedef/using statement instead of a plain C++ enum as I showed ?

I didn't choose the approach with the using declaration myself; clang-tidy applied it automatically in many places. I just wanted to make sure that this change is standard-compliant. Personally, I do not prefer the variant that uses the using declaration.

@SoulfreezerXP I am a bit surprised to hear that. I assume there is a way to configure clang-tidy to allow straightforward enum declaration, since this is the default and most common way of declaring an enum in C++. As you can see in a comments below your question (e.g. by Ahmed AEK), it is the way C++ developers will expect an enum declaration to look like. Maybe clang-tidy will change a typedef to a using, but if you will simply remove both as I showed clang-tidy should not change it.

Yes, exactly for that reason—since I seem to belong to this developer group as well—I wrote this article to verify that it is even compliant.

@SoulfreezerXP I updated my comment. I added that I can understand clang-tidy will change a typedef to a using (because it is more modern). But if you simply modify the enum declaration to use neither (as shown in my answer), clang-tidy should be happy with it.

Yes, I know that, but I'm concerned about the code that was generated through the automated modification. It must be compliant so that people don't encounter issues without realizing it. Since it seems to be completely legitimate, my question has been answered here.

@SoulfreezerXP I finally see. So the issue is that you don't want to (or cannot) modify the existing code, and you just wanted to verify that the automatic modification by clang-tidy is valid.

Yes, exactly, otherwise I would have opened a ticket there. It’s important to me that I, and others, can rely on tools like clang-tidy with confidence.
